# SQL Server is started but didn't listen on any port

Tags: sql-server, windows

I newly installed SQL Server 2012. No database created yet. And I can open the Management Studio with sa/password. The Binn\sqlservr.exe is started as a service and I can see it started in the service list. However, it didn't listening the 1433 port, or even, not listening any port by default, as I checked as below:

```
tasklist|find /I "sql"
```

I got:

```
sqlservr.exe                  5668 Services                   0     40,112 K
```

in which 5668 I think is the PID. And then to get PID = "5668" is listening to which port:

```
netstat -ano | find /I "5668"
```

but I got nothing except blank. On the other hand, after searching posts in this site, I double-checked my SQL Server's configuration: start->All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager-> SQL Server SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration -> Client Protocols -> TCP/IP ->Default Port 1433. There're 3 services, SQL Server(MyInstanceName), SQL Server Agent(MyInstanceName) and SQL Server Browser. The last two is stopped.

SQL Server Configuration Manager-> SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols for MyInstanceName -> TCP/IP is disabled by default, after I enabled it and restart the service and repeat the netstat -ano | find /I "newPIDNum" command I found the

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:52395          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING  5668(newPIDNum)
```

Why 52395 instead of 1433? And I failed to create the DSN using Windows ODBC Data Source administrator which returns me an error: specified SQL server not found. 
Any help for me? Thanks.

Comment: [Default SQL Server Network Configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190198(v=sql.105).aspx) (for 2008, can't find 2012 version but I don't think it's any different)

Comment: Thanks. A really good help for me. Any more comments about my DSN crating?

Comment: It looks like you're using a named instance (only the default instance listens on 1433, so far as I'm aware). Are you including the instance name when trying to create the DSN?

Comment: Yes, when install, I entered a name for Instance. When creating DSN, I was asked to input a DSN name(I entered an arbitary name), SQL server to connect to(This is a drop-down selection box and I tried two choices here both fail, one is (local), another is <.MyInstanceName>),

Comment: I didn't see any other place to include the MyInstanceName yet. And the next button direct me an authentication as well as a <Client Configuration> which I can set the <Server Alias>, <Server Name> and check <Dynamically determine port>.

Answer (score 23):

What made my SQL server listen for `TCP` connections on port 1433 was the following...

1. Configuration Tools / SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. click the instance name in SQL Server Network Configuration
3. enable `TCP` communication
4. Right-click the `TCP` communication entry, choose `Properties`
5. Click the IP addresses tab
6. Enable all non-VMnet IP addresses and enter 1433 in the `Port` entry for "**IPAll**".
7. Restart the SQL Server on SQL Server Services tab
8. Check your configuration with `netstat -an`:

   ```
   C:\>netstat -an | find "1433"
     TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
     TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0                 LISTENING
   ```

Comment: This is only one solution that works for me. Any other manuals not even say about IPAII port. Thanks man, you made my day

Comment: The only thing that worked for me too. This is one of the things that make you wonder who the hell came up with this obscure setting and why is it so difficult to make it work

Answer (score 13):

> Why 52395 instead of 1433

Named instances listen on dynamic ports. Is the job of the [Sql Server Browser Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx) to inform the clients of the actual port. The Sql Browser listens on UDP 1434 and answers questions of the form 'what is the listenning port of instance "foo"?'. Sql Server Browser service is required for both TCP and named pipes protocols. Clients use the SQL Server Browser transparently, no need for special configuration. By simply specifying an instance name in the connection string (or the ODBC DSN), the client library know it has to contact the SQL Server Browser service first.

> There're 3 services, SQL Server(MyInstanceName), SQL Server Agent(MyInstanceName) and SQL Server Browser. The last two is stopped

Obviously for SQL Server Browser to do its job, it needs to be started. Start it, and change the start up type to automatic.

As a side note, an often used alternative configuration is to use static ports for the named instance and specify the port in the connection string (`tcp:<hostname>:<port>`). It has the advantage of taking SQL Server Browser out of the equation, but it requires careful maintenance of clients. Changing the listening port requires orchestrated changes at all clients, all machines, all locations, usually a big pain. I recommend taking the dependency on SQL Server Browser instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Firewalls - 3 of them

People who aren't familiar with more recent versions of Windows (I am not comfortable with any after XP, and was trying to install SQL Server on Windows 10):

- Your firewall needs to be turned of in **3 separate places** (i.e. for 3 different Profiles).

If you only do it for the first one you see (Domain Profile), you will still be left wondering why you can connect to port 80 (IIS) but not 1433 (SQL Server).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet (reputation low since not very active): But disabling Windows Firewall, like mentioned above, is the worst possible answer.
Correct would be: Create firewall rules in "inbound" to allow Port 1433 communication on those local IPs (or all) you need. And I also recommend to set which remote IPs are allowed to connect to that SQL Server.